# I am trying to launch firefox 39.0 browser using selenium but i am getting this error below

Tags: selenium

org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a read of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Please explain what you did and what happened, and include the output!

Comment: Please share your code snippet.Do mention which selenium version you are using  .

Comment: My firefox version is 39.0 i tried with 43.0 also and selenium version is 2.39.0 . So the first step i have added all the jar files successfully and write the simple code..below                      package seleniumbasic1;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class A {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  FirefoxDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http:\\www.gmail.com"); }
 }

Answer (score 0):

you need to update selenium version to 2.48